# Are CRC cards still used for designing your system?

Tags: oop, simulation, crc-cards

CRC cards are known as one of the simple, intuitive method
to simulate your system before creating it.
Many people praises its goodness with a few of criticism 
but I could not find well, solid examples about its actual usage
or good case studies.

YouTube only provides two direct examples how CRC methods
are used - both of them are played in not american, even the
creators of the method are two great american ^^. 
How funny?

So here I want to know how many people actually uses CRC in design session?
Is it still valid or great? Is it worth to investigate, practice and put in many hours?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is largely replaced by UML. Never heard of anyone using CRC, but then again I'm more in the web than corporate development..